# How to do a carousel in jQuery with a circular movement on mouse over?

Tags: jquery

I was wondering if anybody has an idea if this is possible. I wanna do what the jcarousel does but with a mouseover event instead of click. I want that once we have the mouse on the arrow the images keep rotating in an infinite loop. I know how to do the movement and the mouseover event.I would also know how to do this working without the circular "loop", but I can´t seem to figure out how would it be possible to do it with the loop. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
    buttonNextEvent: "mouseenter",
    buttonPrevEvent: "mouseenter"
});
```